# Localization bot links are broken now

Tags: bug, localization, chatbot, transifex

Seems after the recently made upgrade of transifex.com locatization bot links in chat became broken. I.e. link doesn't refer to a reported string.

E.g. you could try [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45165588#45165588) from the ruSO chat (you still need a Transifex account to access the translations).

#### Possible solution:

The old style link like this:

> https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/-1?key=f‌​fbc163020c6e00f2e265b6a1b6653ef

should be transformed into the following:

> https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/-1?q=key%3Affbc163020c6e00f2e265b6a1b6653ef