# Different link parsing among preview mode and in the final

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-preview

The post [Localization bot links are broken now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310756/339911) contains two links to transifex strings. In the question body links look like this:

> [image: final]

I.e. both links have the tail which doesn't recognized as a part of the links (I think such behaviour should be posted as another bug report).

But in the preview mode (if you click "edit" link) of the post, second link includes all of the text as a path:

> [image: preview]

Also the first link's clickable part is differs, but doesn't contain full text.